# Primefaces p:teee horizontal not working and rendering correctly

Tags: primefaces, boost-propertytree

I am doing a very basic example from primefaces showcase

Primefaces Version =  V-6.0.18 
WAS 9

https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/htree/basic.xhtml

There is no difference in code and I see bean being called . I also see in chrome developer nodes being created and style="display-none".

Issues I am having

1) Look and feel of "Root" is not correct I see root with a line strike through.
2) When I click on Root nothing happens , no node expansion  . I do not see any exception been thrown in chrome developer .

NOTE: The code is exactly the same as in the showcase no change

[image]

This is from chrome developer

```
<tr>
  <td class="ui-treenode ui-treenode-parent ui-treenode-collapsed ui-treenode-unselected" data-nodetype="default" data-rowkey="root"><div
      class="ui-treenode-content ui-tree-selectable ui-state-default ui-corner-all">
      <span class="ui-tree-toggler ui-icon ui-icon-plus"></span><span></span>Root
    </div></td>
  <td class="ui-treenode-children-container" style="display: none"><div class="ui-treenode-children">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="ui-treenode-connector"><table class="ui-treenode-connector-table">
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="ui-treenode-connector-line"></td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table></td>
            <td class="ui-treenode ui-treenode-parent ui-treenode-collapsed ui-treenode-unselected" data-nodetype="default" data-rowkey="0"><div
                class="ui-treenode-content ui-tree-selectable ui-state-default ui-corner-all">
                <span class="ui-tree-toggler ui-icon ui-icon-plus"></span><span></span>Node 0
              </div></td>
            <td class="ui-treenode-children-container" style="display: none"><div class="ui-treenode-children">
                <table>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td class="ui-treenode-connector"><table class="ui-treenode-connector-table">
    enter code here
```

I am not sure if it is css issue / JS issue ?

Any help will be appreciated .

Edit:

Just tested without orientation="horizontal"

```
<p:tree value="#{treeBasicView.root}" var="node">
        <p:treeNode>
            <h:outputText value="#{node}" />
        </p:treeNode>
    </p:tree>
```

It works but I wanted horizontal orientation and it does not work

```
<p:tree value="#{treeBasicView.root}" var="node" orientation="horizontal">
        <p:treeNode>
            <h:outputText value="#{node}" />
        </p:treeNode>
    </p:tree>
```

Comment: Hi, I cannot reproduce, please create a full real [mcve] and please try 6.1 or 6.2

Answer (score 0):

Thanks,  Kukeltje for trying to help. Finally, I figured it out. In my current existing project, somehow jquery-ui.css was not present. Once I added jquery-ui.css it started picking up missing icons and it started working seamlessly.